# Error with Spine Atlas file

Tags: cocos2d-x-2.x

i'm using cocos2d-x 2.2.3 and spine 1.9.07.
I've exported "seller.atlas", "seller.json" and "seller.png" by Spine and put them in Resource folder of my project. Then, in init() method I add these code to use skeleton animation

```
skeletonNode = CCSkeletonAnimation::createWithFile("spine/seller.json", "spine/seller.atlas");
skeletonNode->debugSlots = true;
skeletonNode->timeScale = 0.5f;
skeletonNode->setAnimation("walk", true);
skeletonNode->debugBones = true;

CCSize windowSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
skeletonNode->setPosition(ccp(windowSize.width / 2, 50));
addChild(skeletonNode);
```

but It throws out an error like this

```
    void CCObject::release(void)
{
    CCAssert(m_uReference > 0, "reference count should greater than 0");
    --m_uReference;

    if (m_uReference == 0)
    {
        delete this;
    }
}
```

It means that skeletonNode is NULL so it must be something wrong with the atlas file.
But I don't know what wrong is it :(

Any help would be appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because cocos2dx 2.2.3 is using an old spine parser. Spine 1.9 generates atlas files in a different format. there is an extra line of "size: xxx,xxx".
To address this specific problem, add
readLine(0, end, &str);
in Atlas.cpp
before
if (!readValue(end, &str)) return abortAtlas(self);

Note you might run into other problems such as unknown attachment type mesh/skinned mesh since Spine 1.9 using new format. You need to update spine code in 2.2.3 to fix all.

Comment: Yes you are right. I've just updated the spine runtime using the one provided by EsotericSoftware from https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-runtimes and the problem flew away. :D